# How can one utilize an "objective observer", if one cannot be such?

Tags: legal-concepts, jurisprudence

How can one utilize an "objective observer", if one cannot be such?

When this "objective observer" is utilized. E.g.

> X is unlawful, if an objective observer would interpret it as such.

like in

> For purposes of this rule, an objective observer is aware that implicit, institutional, and
> unconscious biases, in addition to purposeful discrimination, have resulted in the unfair exclusion of potential jurors
> in Washington State.

source: https://www.courts.wa.gov/court_rules/?fa=court_rules.display&group=ga&ruleid=gagr37

The particular problematics related to this are discussed in e.g.:

https://www.californialawreview.org/print/what-to-do-about-batson/

Or

https://apnews.com/article/race-and-ethnicity-trials-juries-death-of-george-floyd-racial-injustice-495e7b36e5c1eee6eb2ff4ee35a21987

where in particular they say:

> While the goal objectively is to seat an unbiased jury, both sides try to remove people who may view their case unfavorably.

Thus questioning the practical feasibility of an objective observer.

While the concept is intuitive as "refers to physically appearing", the idea of an objective observer thus seems faulty to me. I would perhaps call it "non- subject dependent circumstances". But then the question could in some cases, does such exist? A challenge should be e.g. the difficulty/impossibility of displaying that someone is biased, because there's no objective instrument for it. And if it's a human judging it, then it cannot be unbiased.

For example, the particular wording in relation to discrimination in the Batson example there seems like it suggests that "an objective observer would treat people equally" or that "it is unfair (to treat people unequally)", which are biases themselves. Thus possibly lending to the idea that "objective observer" may be utilized for "our bias, which we claim objective".

---

Related:

Machine-learning jury

Comment: You claim that this characterization not only exists, but exists often. Show us that this is correct: give appropriate citations.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a question about law, it is a philosophical argument that OP has already decided on an answer for.

Comment: @Studoku But so has a court, who refers to such objective observer. I'm trying to understand how it's possible to make it plausible, when it seems to near "god-given law" to me.

Comment: At least in the question's current state, I think it's on topic, even if it's a *little* philosophical.  Dale's answer addresses it well from a legal perspective.

Answer (score 7):

### The objective observer is not a [real person](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_on_the_Clapham_omnibus)

She is one of a number of imaginary people who are used in law to inform judges and jurors how they should intellectually engage with a legal issue. We may not know or be a reasonable person or an objective observer but we know the characteristics they would have if they existed. The legal usage is not to prove a person is or isn’t an objective observer, it’s to establish the standard they would apply if they were.

It’s worth quoting Lord Reed from *Healthcare at Home Limited v. The Common Services Agency* [2014] UKSC 49 at [1](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_on_the_Clapham_omnibus)-[4]:

> 1. The Clapham omnibus has many passengers. The most venerable is the reasonable man, who was born during the reign of Victoria but remains in vigorous health. Amongst the other passengers are the right-thinking member of society, familiar from the law of defamation, the officious bystander, the reasonable parent, the reasonable landlord, and **the fair-minded and informed observer**, all of whom have had season tickets for many years.
> 2. The horse-drawn bus between Knightsbridge and Clapham, which Lord Bowen is thought to have had in mind, was real enough. But its most famous passenger, and the others I have mentioned, are [legal fictions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legal_fiction). **They belong to an intellectual tradition of defining a legal standard by reference to a hypothetical person**, which stretches back to the creation by Roman jurists of the figure of the bonus paterfamilias...
> 3. It follows from the nature of the reasonable man, as a means of describing a standard applied by the court, that it would be misconceived for a party to seek to lead evidence from actual passengers on the Clapham omnibus as to how they would have acted in a given situation or what they would have foreseen, to establish how the reasonable man would have acted or what he would have foreseen. **Even if the party offered to prove that his witnesses were reasonable men, the evidence would be beside the point.** **The behaviour of the reasonable man is not established by the evidence of witnesses, but by the application of a legal standard by the court.** The court may require to be informed by evidence of circumstances which bear on its application of the standard of the reasonable man in any particular case; but it is then for the court to determine the outcome, in those circumstances, of applying that impersonal standard.
> 4. In recent times, some additional passengers from the European Union have boarded the Clapham omnibus. This appeal is concerned with one of them: the reasonably well-informed and normally diligent tenderer.

The particular objective observer required in Washington jury selection has these characteristics:

> … an objective observer is aware that implicit, institutional, and unconscious biases, in addition to purposeful discrimination, have resulted in the unfair exclusion of potential jurors in Washington State.

It doesn’t matter that you or I may not hold that view, the hypothetical objective observer **does** an therefore:

> If the court determines that an objective observer could view race or ethnicity as a
> factor in the use of the peremptory challenge, then the peremptory challenge shall be denied.

So, when the judge considers the challenge they have to view it in the light “that implicit, institutional, and unconscious biases, in addition to purposeful discrimination, have resulted in the unfair exclusion of potential jurors”  whether they believe that or not. If a person who held that view “could” view the challenge as factoring in race or ethnicity then it must be denied.

This long-standing legal tradition is founded in human psychology: we’re actually really good at imagining what other people will do if we make the effort. The hypothetical person is an idealised individual who doesn’t have to worry about money, or children or what the neighbours think. By making an effort to think like they would diverse real humans can actually produce amazingly consistent responses.

Comment: Good answer. But how is "We may not know or be a reasonable person or an objective observer but we know the characteristics they would have if they existed." trustworthy? Like how is it possible to demonstrate that it's possible to actually know what the objective observer is? Can one devise an algorithm for it for example that displays that it minimizes bias? And e.g. in the discrimination example, one could posit that: "an assumption about equality is a bias, not some kind of objective" and that the jury is now biased towards equality as objective.

Comment: This also seemed to suggest to me (from a mathematical idea of bias) that they should not look for "objective", but "average" as to minimize "extreme cases". So that the objective, reasonable observer is "a decision that's average idea about all the options present".

Comment: @mavavilj why do you think the idea is to eliminate bias? The express provision of the law is to bias jury selection to the *defined* objective standard. It may be that the average person does or doesn’t have this bias (probably they do) - that’s why we don’t use average people, we use archetypes.

Comment: "Objective" does not make (literal) sense, if it's biased. So then the concept of "objective observer" is some sort of linguistic hoax. A physical object has objective presence, if sensing the characteristics does not depend on observer. Any interpretation added breaks the ideal of objective. The mere selection of a jury is already biased by e.g. sample size. Even more, a "varied jury" is biased towards variance. While a low-variance jury is also biased.

Comment: @mavavilj nothing is truly objective - quantum physics tells us that.

Comment: I would not argue about that people cannot be objectively agreeable on common sense level such as that "plant leaves are green" or "a murder has occured, because a person is dead and it's visible that he/she has been attacked". But if the interpretation depends on what's thought and said, then it's complex. Since another person's "crime" may be another's idea of "freedom". Or another person's crime might be another person's privileged right. Because it's value-dependent. How would one e.g. decide, whether workplace bullying is about freedom from unwanted people or about causing harm?

Comment: In the workplace bullying example, there's clearly no objective reference, if no-one is physically harmed. Rather, there are competing social interests. And according to some law is specifically about these competing interests: https://lawaspect.com/balancing-competing-interests/ But is there objectivity to it?

Answer (score 6):

The key word in your quoted text is "**if**" meaning that such a person need not be present at the relevant time.

Rather, a judge or jury using, for example, their life experiences, common sense and all the evidence before them to determine objectively what a reasonable person would do in the same or similar circumstances. A process some refer to as [The Man on the Clapham Omnibus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_on_the_Clapham_omnibus).

<sub>**NB This answer is based on the question's first incarnation (viewable in the edit history by those with enough rep) - see DaleM's post for an answer following the revisions**</sub>

Comment: No I still think "objectively" and "reasonable" is fallacious. Based on that no subject is ever fully unbiased. A practical example could be: a disabled person is objectively less capable, therefore a reasonable person would discriminate against disabled people (since the disabled is objectively less capable and therefore it's reasonable). Yet this is unlawful. And then we could notice that there's no objective, but "based on subjective value preferences".

Comment: I don't believe any ethical statement can be ultimately decided "objectively". But they can be decided on "what a reasonable person would expect not to happen", such as "a reasonable person would expect not to be assasinated randomly".

Comment: I don't really follow that logic, and not all discrimination is unlawful in some/most (all?) jurisdictions

Comment: Isn't the point of the objective observer to decide on such "difference in personal gain"? So that ideally from biased individuals (including the judge) no-one would gain their preference? Or at least this is an ideal. I.e. the absence of judicial bias.